# Enable or disable qtip on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip, qtip2

I use asp.net mvc razor code.
I use qtip to give a show popup on mouseover.
I have a checkbox in the settings page,which is used to enable/disable the qtip.

Here is my code:

```
function tooltip(a) {
    Sapppid = document.getElementById("s" + a).textContent;
    Sapppid = Sapppid.replace("s", "");
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.pathname + "Scheduler/getappointmentdetails",
        type: "POST",
        data: { sharedappid: Sapppid }
    })
    .success(function (result) {
        document.getElementById('ApptDetails').value = result;
    });

    $("#" + a).qtip({
        overwrite: false,
        content: {
            text: "...",
            button: 'Close',
            ajax: {
                url: window.location.pathname + "Scheduler/Eventdetails/" + Sapppid,
                type: 'Post',
                success: function (result) {} 
            } 
        },
        style: {
            classes: '',
            width: 500
        },
        position: {
            my: 'right bottom center',
            at: 'middle right center',
            target: $("#" + a)
        },
        show: {
            ready: true,
            solo: true
        },
        hide: {
            when: { event: 'mouseout unfocus' }, fixed: true, delay: 200
        }
    });   
}
```

I design qtip to showup on a dynamic content. I use qtip2. I din't find any documentation to disable or enable in the site.

This is the only code i found, but couldnt figure out where to apply this.:

> http://qtip2.com/api#api.disable

```
api.disable(true);

// Enable it again
api.disable(false);
```

Comment: apply on button or something else

Answer (score 2):

attach an onclick event to your checkbox and place the disable within the qtip function on the element you're targetting

Code Example:

```
$('.checkbox').on('click', function(){
    $('.dynamic').qtip('disable', true);
});
```

Give this a try and let me know if it works in the comments

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
    $('.checkbox').on('click', function(){
        var api = $('.dynamic').qtip('api');
        api.disable(true);
    });
```